# Google Clock how to remove added city time

Tags: settings, clock

I am using default Google Clock application for time and alarm setting on my Moto X4. Moving to clock on it, there's globe icon under home time, which is used to set and display different city time. I have added some cities, and then I cannot see any option to delete that city. On tapping, Menu->Settings on top-right corner, I cannot found any option to delete it. How to delete those added city time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Google Clock.
2. Switch to Clock menu.
3. Press and Hold city time you need to remove, then you can see a `Delete` icon there(globe icon changed to dustbin icon), swipe down to Delete it (Android 8 Oreo).

Answer (score 11):

1. Open clock function.
2. Press the + to "search for a city".
3. Type in the city you wish to remove.
4. Uncheck it.

Comment: Only this method is working on Android latest versions +11

Answer (score 5):

In the new, redesigned app, swiping to the left on the clock you want to remove does the job.

Answer (score 2):

On my Android V. 9 the Help function directed me to:

1. Open Clock function
2. Press the location to be deleted
3. Drag the location to the bottom of the screen, it should disappear

I did this and it worked.

Note: This does not work on the new, redesigned Google clock app.

Answer (score 0):

Just type the city after clicking the globe, then uncheck that checkmark.